# How to pull up a root element in a table referencing itself with a foreign key ? (loop ?)

Tags: sql, postgresql, loops

For instance lets say that you have a table Person like so :

```
Id  Name    Birthdate   Parent
1   Hans    1960/10/15  null
2   Svend   1985/01/23  1
3   Peter   2004/03/02  2
```

Parent is a foreign key on the Person table.
I want to go back all the way to the oldest parent starting from a child.
For example, starting from Peter, is it possible to retrieve Hans in SQL ?

There can be possibly dozens of intermediary rows between the starting row and the ending row.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Try a recursive WITH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Recursive CTE (Recursive Common Table Expression) will do what you want:

```
with recursive
x as (
  select *, 1 as my_level from my_table where id = 3 -- Peter's id
  union all
  select
    t.*, x.my_level + 1
  from my_table t
  join x on x.parent = t.id
)
select * from x order by my_level desc limit 1
```